# QGIS: use SVG file as a layer?

Tags: qgis, vector-layer

I am new to QGIS, so be patient with me if this is rather basic. (And I am still learning the terminology as well.)

I have a very nice, and detailed vector map in an Adobe Illustrator format. I can, of course, save this as an SVG, EPS, or PDF file.

What I would like to do is add this as a vector layer in QGIS and then georeference it. Once complete, I would then like to use it as a base to add other features, etc. and then export it as a PDF or SVG. (I have worked out how to use Map Composer, so that is fine.)

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to import this file? I have tried SVG, PDF, and EPS formats but with no luck.
2. If this is possible, how do I georeference it? Is there a QGIS plugin that will (for example) allow me to select reference points?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: You can also save as DXF and load into QGIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691541/qgis-how-to-import-svg-or-raster-images-into-quantum-gis (geo-reference the dxf as Joseph describes)

Answer (score 3):

For a good tutorial, check this post: [Georeferencing Topo Sheets and Scanned Maps](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html)

---

For your case, I would probably do the following:

1. Convert your svg file into a png (if I open up an svg in Internet Explorer, I can right-click and use the `Save As...` option to save it as a png file).
2. Load QGIS and make sure the **Georeferencer** plugin is installed/enabled from the menu bar:

   ```
   Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
   ```
3. Click the **Georeferencer** plugin icon from the toolbar or alternatively from the menu bar:

   ```
   Raster > Georeferencer > Georeferencer
   ```
4. Select the `Open Raster` tool from the **Georeferencer** interface and select your png file:

   [image: Open raster]
5. Then click on your image to add in GCP points for referencing the image with map coordinates. Once done, click the `Transformation Settings` button to set your configuration, especially the `Output raster` option:

   [image: Configuration]
6. Once done, click the `Start Georeferencing` button and hopefully you will have a GeoTiff raster:

   [image: Georeferencing]